# 24V signal switching optccoupler

Tags: transistors, led, opto-isolator, 24v

We have a robot, and it has 32 digital output, fed into a homemade PCB.

On the PCB we have optocouplers, which have a forward voltage around 1.2-1.3V.

So I need to drop the voltage a lot. That's why I use resistors.  See the following schematic. [image]

The output of the optocoupler is connected to an I/O expanderm and when the 24V circuit is closed the pin of the I/O expander is pulled to ground. It works great.

One problem: R2 needs to dissipate 0.25W, times 32 outputs is 8W in heat.

And that is a bit too much. So I'm looking for other ways to make the same schematic but a bit more efficient.

I came up with the following idea:

The 24 V will switch the transistor and turn on led2.

In total the circuits pulls 135.46 mW, that is 80% better than the first idea.
[image]

Is there even a better way do this?

Comment: Why do you use an optocoupler if your second circuit can, without any issue, break the galvanic isolation between both sides of the optocoupler?

Comment: Is the purpose of the optocouplers level shifting or galvanic isolation? What is the maximum frequency of the signals?

Comment: How is 0.135W 80% better than 0.25W? It's closer to 50%.

Comment: It's not very clear what your goal is here, anyway. What is the point of this circuit? Why is there no pullup resistor on the output of the optoisolator?

Comment: You could also run your optos at a lower current such as 1 to 2 mA for low speed digital signalling

Comment: @Marcus Müller The second circuit is a qiuck mock-up of what I thought would also be a good idea. Led 1 now connect to pin 5 of the optcoupler, but the first circuit  is the one used right now.

The I/O expander has pullup resistor internal, so the state is alwasy high. to make the state low, i need to pull the pin to low.. connect to GND.

Comment: @sstobbe does the optos still switch at that currect level?

Comment: @Hearth The point of the circuit is to detect the status of the outputs of the robot itself. (High or Low) . the software does the work further.

Comment: @stefandekraker still not quite sure what the motivation for an optocoupler is in this circuit?

Comment: @MarcusMüller So the 5V part of the PCB is protected, when (for some reason) the input voltage is much higher than 24V, all the low voltage`s part are isolated.

Comment: Well you only need to drive the opto hard enough to gaurentee you can sink all the pull-up current of the IO expander which I would guess is around 100 uA. Start there and work backwards

Comment: @stefandekraker but then you mustn't ever use the 5V supply on the 24 V side, so your second circuit would be a no-go!

Comment: The opto coupler application with the grounds common between the two sides begs the real question that there is no real isolation between the 24V circuits and the 5V circuits of the MCU.

Comment: 1.8K resistor is too small.  CNY17F-4 only appears to need 10mA.

Answer (score 1):

Try a more efficient optoisolator. FOD817 for example only need 1mA  https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FOD814-D.PDF  (24V - 1.2V)/.001 = 22.8K resistor, dissipating just 0.023W

Answer (score 0):

If optical isolation is not necessary, you can do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvR6ti.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor divider will give 4.8 V out when the switch is closed. That's a logic high.
When switch is open, the GPIO is pulled LOW through 100 K resistor.

Power dissipation = 24*24/500000 = 1.152 mW per channel

For 32 channels, total power dissipation = 36.864 mW